# Raspberry Pi 3 and the new Google AIY Voice Kit SDK - how to adapt the old SDK mod guides?

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk, philips-hue, google-aiy

I have just purchased a `Google AIY Voice Kit` to use with my `Raspberry Pi` and I am trying to follow instructions on how to use the voice commands to control a `Philips Hue lighting system`.

The problem is I have no coding experience whatsoever and all of the instructions in the links below are related to the old version of the `Google AIY Voice Kit SDK` and I don't know how to adapt them into the new version (i.e. they refer to an `actions.py` file in a certain folder that no longer exists).

[Google Voice AIY Mods](http://ktinkerer.co.uk/list-mods-raspberry-pi-aiy-project/)
[Philips Hue Support for Google Assistant - Install Guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=114&t=183761)

The link below contains the related folders that are on my Raspberry Pi's `/home/pi` directory. I just want to know what I need to copy from the Philips Hue guide and where I need to copy it to in the folders I have on the Raspberry Pi. If anyone is feeling up to it, I can also provide remote access to the Raspberry Pi via `VNC`.

[Google Voice AIY Kit Folders from Raspberry Pi](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gmdga0vuepvukho/AACTGP1e1oi3A5jubDkZgCRma?dl=0)